# White line in footer of EE Admin CP

Tags: admin

For a while, I seen a white line appear in the footer of my admin (see the screenshot). Can anyone tell me the best way to debug it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a browser inspector and examine the generated source. Chrome's web inspector is ideal for this, just right click the line and select Inspect Element. This may give you a clue as to what is creating it.